# DIY Bathroom Reno. How many panels to remove? How much wall to demo?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, renovation, drywall-mud, kerdi

[image]Background: Home built in 1962

Started demolition to the guest bathroom and gutted the tub, tile, and backboard. I would like to know how much of the drywall/cement board should I remove past the tub line?

[image]

Comment: Look at drywall at toilet and vanity , If mold keep going.

Comment: If there is no mold, should I pull enough wall out to expose the next stud over so I can secure the replacement kerdi board?

Comment: 1962 I would think all, lead paint, Up grade any electrical.

Comment: Yes or plumb a line ,cut it add a stud.

Comment: Looks like the old rock lath with skim coat of plaster.They 4x2 Nailed on.

Comment: You are renovating.... so it is up to you. What is your goal? At this point, pull it all, get new flooring in, greeboard, expand your switch plates, insulate, add vent fans, etc. get it all. And never have to worry about matching drywall to the existing board.

Comment: It doesn't look like it's been repainted a dozen times, so the bathroom was quite possibly renovated much more recently.  So, I wouldn't assume lead paint (even back then, cheaper paint actually often did not have lead), but I would test the areas broken paint.  As noybman said, what's your goal?  If you wanted to have a working half-bath through the renovation, or minimize cost, those are important considerations, too.